# JSON Schema - Setting Static Names

Tags: json, validation, schema, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

My example JSON which I'm trying to convert into a schema is:

```
{
          "nodeID": "5f9f5dbe0c3ab520c2b44bb0",
          "type": "block",
          "coords": [
            517.2814214277396,
            769.7697271579176
          ],
          "data": {
            "name": "Block",
            "color": "standard",
            "steps": [
              "5f9f5dbe0c3ab520c2b44bb1"
            ]
          }
        }
```

and I've converted it to this schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "nodeID": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "data": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "intent": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "diagramID": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "mappings": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {}
        },
        "next": {
          "type": "null"
        },
        "ports": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {}
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "name",
        "intent",
        "diagramID",
        "mappings",
        "next",
        "ports"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "nodeID",
    "type",
    "data"
  ]
}
```

In the example JSON, you can see the type = "block".
How in the schema can I ensure that when a JSON is checked it make sure to check that the type key is == "block"?

Thank You! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an enum per https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html#enumerated-values

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "nodeID": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "type": {
      "type": "string",
      "enum": ["block"]
    },
    "data": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "intent": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "diagramID": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "mappings": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {}
        },
        "next": {
          "type": "null"
        },
        "ports": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {}
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "name",
        "intent",
        "diagramID",
        "mappings",
        "next",
        "ports"
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "nodeID",
    "type",
    "data"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Or in more recent versions of JSON Schema, a single enum value can also be specified with `const`.